# 3D scanning to Blender with surface map preserved

Tags: import

Is there a scanning system (or app. - Software) that can convert a 3D object to Blender with also it's surface texture (ex. a shampoo bottle with it's descriptive label)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can try any photogrammetry software like meshroom or colmap, Those apps will create meshes and textures based on series of photograps. But, serously, for a shampoo bottle?  It might be a lot easier to model and create the correct texture by hand.

Comment: Thank you.The shampoo bottle wa only an example to explain that I needed the maps also. It would be more complex objects in reality.